# Salesforce integration using Informatica

Tags: soql, reporting, integration, informatica

I want to use a salesforce report as my source and import it into a SQL server database. But I assume, we cant use reports as our source in Informatica cloud.
If I use Saved Query as my source, would it allow me to use custom SOQL query that refers Salesforce objects/fields and creates the report on fly. I tested the SOQL query on workbench and it works fine. But not sure if SOQL query is accepted as a source in Saved query feature of Informatica Cloud.

Any help or inputs would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Shirish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean the "Informatica Cloud", service to which you log in via https://app.informaticaondemand.com/ma/ ? I've once used a saved query as base for DELETE operation, it was SOQL all right. You shouldn't have any problems.

I was building a task flow that was upserting some data and as last step I needed to kill obsolete records, not modified in last 30 days. `SELECT Id FROM Object__c WHERE LastModifiedDate != LAST_N_DAYS:30` + delete operation was enough.

Just make sure your connector to target org uses fairly fresh API version. From what I remember support for saved queries was added in v 33.

Comment: Right, my query is referencing two objects which are look up to the main object.. so something like this should work right? 
SELECT Name, External_ID__c,sm1e__Asset_Tag__c,sm1e__Start_Time__c,sm1e__End_Time__c,Event_Validated__c,Event_Duration__c,sm1e__Status__c,DC_Capacity__c,Plant_Derated_Capacity__c,Excusable_Hours__c,Event_Violation_Hours__c,Total_Excusable_Allowed_Hours__c FROM sm1e__Operational_Event__c WHERE sm1e__Asset_Tag__c LIKE '3000%' AND sm1e__Status__c != 'Canceled' AND sm1e__Start_Time__c >= Today

Comment: I see no reason why not. If you encounter any trouble just download the operations log. Why do you want it to be a saved query instead of normal export task with column mapping, filters, all 6 steps in the wizard?

Comment: I am trying to export a report, which is pulling data from 2 different objects. Normal export task would only allow me to reference one object.. thoughts?

Comment: The query you've pasted doesn't have any relationships (dots) in it so I'm not sure what you're talking about... But no, it's possible to export data like `SELECT Name, Account.Name FROM Contact` in one export task. In Source (step 2) use "multiple" option. That should let you pick the related tables and then in Data Mapping step you should have new columns. Sorry I can't give screenshots, I'm not working with the company where I was using Informatica Cloud anymore.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but even in the license our company has, we cant use multiple object option (it is greyed out), but I signed up a trial environment with informatica and saved query as source is working fine with my soql. Thanks for the information.